# How can I get current autoincrement value

Tags: database, sqlite

How can I get last autoincrement value of specific table right after I open database? It's not `last_insert_rowid()` because there is no insertion transaction. In other words I want to know in advance which number autoincrement will choose when inserting new row for particular table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how the autoincremented column has been defined.

If the column definition is `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`, then SQLite will keep the largest ID in an internal table called [`sqlite_sequence`](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#seqtab).

If the column definition does NOT contain the keyword `AUTOINCREMENT`, SQLite will use its ‘regular’ routine to determine the new ID. From the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html):

> The usual algorithm is to give the newly created row a ROWID that is
>   one larger than the largest ROWID in the table prior to the insert. If
>   the table is initially empty, then a ROWID of 1 is used. If the
>   largest ROWID is equal to the largest possible integer
>   (9223372036854775807) then the database engine starts picking positive
>   candidate ROWIDs at random until it finds one that is not previously
>   used. If no unused ROWID can be found after a reasonable number of
>   attempts, the insert operation fails with an [SQLITE_FULL](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html) error. If no
>   negative ROWID values are inserted explicitly, then automatically
>   generated ROWID values will always be greater than zero.

I remember reading that, for columns without `AUTOINCREMENT`, the only surefire way to determine the next ID is to [VACUUM](http://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) the database first; that will reset all ID counters to the largest existing ID for that table + 1.  But I can’t find that quote anymore, so this may no longer be true.

---

That said, I agree with **slash_rick_dot** that fetching auto-incremented IDs beforehand is a bad idea, especially if there’s even a remote chance that another process might write to the database at the same time.

Comment: According to sqlite documentation, `INTEGER` and `PRIMARY KEY` should be set in order for engine to autoincrement the value. I've tried to set `AUTOINCREMENT` but it doesn't work.

Comment: I have exclusive access to database and no other process have access to db.

Comment: @Pablo: Yes, for a key to become an alias for the ROWID, it always needs to be `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`. Adding the `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword only changes the way the next ID is calculated. It works exactly as described in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1).

Answer (score 1):

Different databases implement auto-increment differently.  But as far as I know, none of them will answer the question you are asking.

The auto increment feature is intended to create a unique ID for a newly added table row.  If a row hasn't been inserted yet, then the feature hasn't produced the id.

And it makes sense...  If you did get the next auto increment number, what would you do with it?  Likely the intent is to assign it as the primary key of the not-yet-inserted new row.  But between the time you got the id, and the time you used it to insert the row, the database could have used that id to insert a row for another process.

Your choices are this:  manage the creation of ids yourself, or wait until rows are inserted before using their auto-created identifiers.